# Sinatra session not preserved with Rack::FiberPool

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack, thin, fiber

The session is not preserved between requests, though I can't see what I'm doing wrong. Code!

```rb
require 'sinatra'
require 'rack/fiber_pool'

class SessionTest < Sinatra::Base
  use Rack::FiberPool
  enable :sessions
  set :session_secret, "foobar"

  get '/' do
        body { session.inspect } #This is always '{}'!
  end

  get '/a' do
    session['user'] = "bob"
    redirect '/'
  end
end

run SessionTest.new
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'rack/fiber_pool'

class SessionTest < Sinatra::Base
  enable :sessions
  set :session_secret, "foobar"

  get '/' do
        body { session.inspect } #This is always '{}'!
  end

  get '/a' do
    session['user'] = "bob"
    redirect '/'
  end
end

use Rack::FiberPool
run SessionTest.new
```

Otherwise Sinatra will set up the fiber pool after the session middleware, which doesn't work. This is not a bug but caused by the way `Rack::FiberPool` works.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out replacing `enable :sessions` with `use Rack::Session::Cookie` is enough to make it work.

But why!?